# Parsing XML safely

Tags: c#, xml, xml-documentation

I have been asked to write a method that takes the following structure of XML, and parse it into a List<> of objects:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<comments>
    <comment>
        <date>11/MAR/2014 10:34am</date>
        <userid>1</userid>
        <text>This is a comment. Please remember to try with some formatting. I'm assuming that some charactors need to be prefixed with a backslash.</text>
    </comment>
    <comment>
        <date>11/MAR/2014 10:37am</date>
        <userid>1</userid>
        <text>This is another comment./r/nIt\'s showing how more than one comment would be stored.\r\n\r\nAlso, this one has some really hardcore escape charactors!</text>
    </comment>
</comments>
```

There can by many 'comments'.

So with my basic knowledge of XML, I tried this:

```
 private List<Comment> XMLToList(string xml)
        {

            var result = new List<Comment>();

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

            XmlNodeList xnList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/comments/comment");

            foreach (XmlNode node in xnList)
            {
                var id = node["userid"].InnerText;
                var date = node["date"].InnerText;
                var text = node["texts"].InnerText;

                result.Add(new Comment
                {
                    Date = DateTime.Parse(date),
                    Text = text,
                    UserID = int.Parse(id)

                });


            }
```

Which works, but is very unsafe. What if nodes are missing? Missplet? Etc.

Is there a way to ensure the XML doc is correctly formatted first?
And then, is there a safer way to get the data?

(I can fix the parsing of dates and int values... this is just a test. It's more the accessing of the nodes that I am trying to resolve).

Can it be done with Linq maybe?

Comment: "Is there a way to ensure the XML doc is correctly formatted first?" You create a schema and validate the XML according to that schema.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with LINQ to XML easily:

```
var comments = XDocument.Parse(xml).Descendants("comment")
            .Select(x => new  Comment
            {
               Date = x.Element("date") != null ? (DateTime)x.Element("date") : default(DateTime),
               Text = (string)x.Element("text"),
               UserID =x.Element("userid") != null ? (int)x.Element("userid") : default(int)
            }).ToList();
```

The key point is using an explicit cast while receiving the values.I have added some null-checks to avoid `ArgumentNullException`.It is throwing when you trying to cast null to ValueType.String is not a problem, it just returns as null.

If you want to ensure that the xml format is valid you can use `try/catch` like this:

```
try
{
      // parse the xml file
}
catch (XmlException ex)
{
     // this exception is thrown by Parse method 
     // when the xml file format is invalid
 }
```

Comment: That worked! Now I just need to find a way to ensure that the format is OK for this code. The schema validation is what I need next.

Comment: @Craig I understand. the simplest way is using try/catch. I will update my answer for that

Comment: @Craig what do you mean exacly by invalid schema ? do you want to know whether the file format is invalid or whether the all necessary elements are exists? because they are different things.you can handle two situations differently.and if you wish you can define an Xml Schema and validate your xml, take a look at the documentation :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3740e0b5(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks @Selman22 - We're discussing the try/catch idea now, as opposed to an XSD schema check, which seems overkill. I just want to be sure that there are fields in my 'comment' section, for 'date', 'userid' and 'text' and that they're valid. The Try/Catch could do that very simply. Is this an accepted pattern? The chances that the XML is invalid is extremely slim. If the xml doesn't have the values I mentioned above - it's invalid. So, the try/catch seems easier and - fit for purpose. But, is this acceptable?

Comment: @Craig yes.But you should remove my Null-Checks because it won't throw exception even if the some values are null :) I would suggest you to create a method for example `ValidateElement` and inside of that method check your elements, if something is null return false.and you can use that method with `Where` before trying to Select your Elements and get only valid elements with `Select`. Or if you want  to ensure that all elements contains the necessary elements then you can easily remove null-checks and use try catch. it will  throw exception as soon as it finds null.