# What kind of data structure should be used here?

Tags: c#, data-structures

I am writing a C# application that has lots of user inputs of various types (strings, doubles, booleans). I need to store all these inputs in a single data structure. There are several hundreds of these inputs, so the data structure that holds them should have a hierarchy (categories, subcategories, etc.). The final input value is wrapped into a class `InputProperty<T>` that stores the actual value and some additional data. Categories and properties might be structured something like this:

```
Input data
-catA
--catAA
---propAAA
---propAAB
--catAB
---catABA
----propABAA
---propABA
-catB
--propBA
-catC
--catCA
---catCAA
----propCAAA
```

And so on. Each category can have sub-categories, or input properties, or both.

The requirements are:

1. Ability to access any category or property in a type-safe way, for example `inputData.catA.catAA.propAAA` (meaning the IDE would notify me if I am trying to access a category/property that doesn't exist).
2. Ability to get a list of all properties in a certain category or any of it's subcategories (for example, call `catA.GetAllProperties()`, which would return a list with references to `propAAA`, `propAAB`, `propABAA`, `propABA`).
3. Ability to easily serialize/deserialize and deep-copy this data structure.

So far, I considered two potential solutions:

1. Have each category as a unique class that extends an interface and base class that provides that `GetAllProperties` functionality. Subcategories and input properties are fields in this class. This satisfies requirements 1 and 2 but not 3, and also complicates the code a lot because of how many classes I need to write which are essentially the same.
2. Have a single category class with dictionary `subcategories` and dictionary `inputProperties`, and build the hierarchy by filling these dictionaries. This satisfies requirements 2 and 3, but not 1, since the only way to navigate through the hierarchy becomes `inputData.subcategories["catA"].subcategories[catAA].inputProperties["AAB"]`, which requires me to remember the exact category structure, and the IDE won't warn me if I made a mistake until I compile. Also I'd probably need to store all the names of categories and properties as string enums so I can at least avoid typing mistakes, but C# doesn't support string enums, so I'd have to use workarounds. This doesn't feel like a cannon solution either.

Can you suggest a better solution?

Comment: Are `CatA` and `CatB` of the same type or are they completely different?

Comment: @Luuk, they can be basically the same type, but will contain different subcategories and input properties.

Comment: I was thinking if you could store it in an [XML](https://codeshare.io/OdbyOx), but that would have some _challenges_ .   And only make sense if the structure is really dynamic.  (I am just a noob with C# )

Comment: Well, I might want to serialize it to XML, but I first need to have it in my application with ability to access it in a type-safe way like I described in my post :)

Comment: Type safety can be done by adding attributes in the [XML](https://codeshare.io/OdbyOx) which are checked when reading/updating the data, that why I said some _challenges_

Comment: How is that done? Do you know of any examples of this?

Comment: A quick search revealed: [Parsing XML safely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22315933/parsing-xml-safely), a longer search might reveal more ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already noticed, there is no perfect solution. As static typing seems more important to you, you can have an abstract class that defines a method to get all the sub-properties. Here it goes :

```
public abstract class Config
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> GetAllProperties(object? target = null, string propName = "")
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        target ??= this;

        var properties = target.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var configType = typeof(Config);
        var subCategories = properties.Where(r => r.PropertyType.BaseType == configType).ToArray();
        var props = properties.Where(r => r.PropertyType.BaseType != configType).ToArray();

        foreach (var subCategory in subCategories)
        {
            var targetValue = subCategory.GetValue(target);
            var subProperties = GetAllProperties(targetValue, subCategory.Name);

            foreach (var (key, value) in subProperties)
            {
                dict.Add(key, value);
            }
        }

        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            var targetPropName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(propName) ? prop.Name : $"{propName}.{prop.Name}";
            dict.Add(targetPropName, prop.GetValue(target)!);
        }

        return dict;
    }
}
```

And you define your config like this :

```
public class RootConfig : Config
{
    public CatA CatA { get; set; }

    public CatB CatB { get; set; }

    public CatC CatC { get; set; }
}

public class CatA : Config
{
    public CatAA CatAA { get; set; }
    public CatAB CatAB { get; set; }
}
public class CatAB : Config
{
    public CatABA CatABA { get; set; }
    public string PropABA { get; set; }
}
public class CatABA : Config
{
    public string PropABAA { get; set; }
}
// this continues
```

Lets construct a config :

```
      var mySuperDuperConfig = new RootConfig
      {
          CatA = new()
          {
              CatAA = new()
              {
                  PropAAA = "AAA hello",
                  PropAAB = 42
              },
              CatAB = new()
              {
                  CatABA = new()
                  {
                      PropABAA = "ABAA_xyz"
                  },
                  PropABA = "ABA_X"
              }
          },
          CatB = new()
          {
              PropBA = 1.9              

          },
          CatC = new()
          {
              CatCA = new()
              {
                  CatCAA = new()
                  {
                      PropCAAA = 1.3f
                  }
              }
          }
      };
```

This can be serialized to JSON or deserialized from json. Will output like this :

```
{
  "CatA": {
    "CatAA": {
      "PropAAA": "AAA hello",
      "PropAAB": 42
    },
    "CatAB": {
      "CatABA": {
        "PropABAA": "ABAA_xyz"
      },
      "PropABA": "ABA_X"
    }
  },
  "CatB": {
    "PropBA": 1.9
  },
  "CatC": {
    "CatCA": {
      "CatCAA": {
        "PropCAAA": 1.3
      }
    }
  }
}
```

See it in [action](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RFOOtd)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this example, really appreciate it. This is better than what I had. The only issue is that defining this structure and initializing is done separately, so I would have to keep track of both when I want to add/change anything in this structure. The idea is that this structure is first initialized with default values (and the structure itself remains static), and then later the values of these props are filled in as need arises. Is it possible to merge definition and initialization somehow?

Comment: "Is it possible to merge definition and initialization somehow":  Nope, there is no type-safe way to achieve this. Maybe using some sort of `Source Generator`  mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview) might give you a better developer experience.

Comment: I meant, why have the categories and read/write properties, rather than having them as read-only? For example, in `RootConfig`, instead of having `public CatA CatA { get; set; }` have `public CatA CatA = new CatA {...}` or similar, and so on? Or would this cause issues down the road?

Comment: @JustinasRubinovas source generators might be a better fit if the source of the truth is the configuration itself. But you will need to add some conventions, annotations, etc. to your configuration file.

Comment: @JustinasRubinovas Do You want init-only properties? If so you can change all the `set;` parts into `init` and then `mySuperDuperConfig.CatB.PropBA = 3.2;` will error.

Comment: Like I wrote in my initial post, the final properties themselves will be an objects that wrap user input data along with some additional data, and the fields of these objects should be readable and writeable. However, the number of these properties, as well as their position in the category hierarchy, and the category hierarchy, can be fixed (init-only). To put simply, the values of properties should be writeable, but the category hierarchy should be fixed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255226/discussion-between-justinas-rubinovas-and-eldar).